# Can I get data from localstorage using php

Tags: javascript, php, local-storage

Can I get data from localstorage using php if yes then tell me how
in localstorage data set like this

```
<script>
var i=0;
function inc()
{
    i+=1;
    localStorage.setItem("qnum", i);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Using php? javascript is client-side. PHP is server-side. This is javascript.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, you can't. PHP runs on your server, the `localStorage` is only available in the browser of the client.

The only way is to read the `localStorage` via JavaScript, and send the result to your server via ajax.

Answer (score 9):

I tried with this code and it worked fine.

```
$Data = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('key'));</script>";
print_r($Data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage` is something that is kept on the client side. There is no data transmitted to the server side.

You can only get the data with JavaScript and you could sent it to the server side with Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Another explanation goes like this: Your browser does not understand php, only javascript (along with html & css). Therefore, you need to read and set LocalStorage with Javascript and send it to a server, like Markus says.

Answer (score 0):

```
$Data = "<script>document.write(localStorage.getItem('key'));</script>";
```

PHP can not handle||add logic with $Data. I think you need to try to use cookie (**trick: if you want to smooth/storage data, try to use localStorage to sync data with cookie)

I try to add some feature with that code (foreach then call item in data), but it not correct. Because we print_r($Data) it will show content of localStorage, but it just show when you open browser. Before browser load, the value of $Data just string (don't have value in localStorage)

so, I still you localStorage in javascript, but I have a function to sync localStorage to cookie for PHP can read value

```
function sync_cookie() { 

let cart = localStorage.getItem("key); 

if (!cart) { return; } 

cart = JSON.parse(cart); let cart_cookie = []; 

cart.forEach(function (item) { 

cart_cookie.push(item.id) }) 

setCookie("key", JSON.stringify(cart_cookie)) }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "PHP can not handle||add logic with $Data"? Why should both a cookie and localStorage work better? Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: I try to add some feature with that code (foreach then call item in data), but it not correct. Because we print_r($Data) it will show content of localStorage, but it just show when you open browser. Before browser load, the value of $Data just string (don't have value in localStorage)

Thank for you ask, I updated my answer